# Connecting to Salesforce Problems C#

Tags: c#, salesforce

I am getting the following error and can not seem to figure out why.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).

error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'iDdataPrep.SFDC.ListViewRecordColumn[]' to 'iDdataPrep.SFDC.ListViewRecordColumn'

error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'iDdataPrep.SFDC.ListViewRecordColumn[]' to 'iDdataPrep.SFDC.ListViewRecordColumn'

error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'iDdataPrep.SFDC.ListViewRecordColumn' to 'iDdataPrep.SFDC.ListViewRecordColumn[]'

error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'iDdataPrep.SFDC.ListViewRecordColumn' to 'iDdataPrep.SFDC.ListViewRecordColumn[]'

Here is my code:

```
public static void sfLogin()
    {
        string userName = "***";
        string password = "***";
        string securityToken = "***";

        SFDC.SforceService sfdcBinding = null;
        SFDC.LoginResult currentLoginResult = null;
        sfdcBinding = new SFDC.SforceService();
        try
        {
            currentLoginResult = sfdcBinding.login(userName, password);
        }
        catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
        {
            sfdcBinding = null;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            sfdcBinding = null;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        sfdcBinding.Url = currentLoginResult.serverUrl;
        sfdcBinding.SessionHeaderValue = new SFDC.SessionHeader();
        sfdcBinding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = currentLoginResult.sessionId;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some .Net integrations with Salesforce do fail due to  a bug in .NET's XmlSerializer as described in the [this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/471297).

The workaround is to add the following element to the Enterprise.WSDL.XML file:

```
<xsd:attribute name="tmp" type="xsd:string" />
```

in the ListViewRecord section. Your Enterprise.WSDL.XML should look like :

```
<complexType name="ListViewRecord">
  <sequence>
    <element name="columns" type="tns:ListViewRecordColumn" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </sequence>
  <b>
    <xsd:attribute name="tmp" type="xsd:string" />
  </b>
</complexType>
```

Check out more in [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000AiPEIA0).

Comment: When I do that then i get this error when adding the service:

Comment: The document at the url file:///J:/AHLI/e3.wsdl was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be <schema> and its namespace should be 'http://www.w3.org/200

Comment: This Works now. I also had to remove one of the [][] in the resources.cs file to make it work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two references to `ListViewRecordColumn[][]` in `Reference.cs`.

Change them both to `ListViewRecordColumn[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem. Here is work around I used. Before you generate the proxy file from the wsdl (such as partner.wsdl), edit the file and add a dummy field to the ListViewRecord defintion.

```
<complexType name="ListViewRecord">
    <sequence>
        <element name="columns"                  type="tns:ListViewRecordColumn" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <element name="dummy"                    type="xsd:int"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

When you generate the proxy file with wsdl.exe it will generate the classes ListViewRecord and ListViewRecordColumn correctly. Then delete the dummy field from the generated code and the classes and properties will be defined as they should be.

```
public partial class ListViewRecord {

    private ListViewRecordColumn[] columnsField;

    /// ** delete this member variable **
    private int dummyField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("columns")]
    public ListViewRecordColumn[] columns {
        get {
            return this.columnsField;
        }
        set {
            this.columnsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// ** delete this property **
    public int dummy {
        get {
            return this.dummyField;
        }
        set {
            this.dummyField = value;
        }
    }
}
```